# DXA (Java) upgrade 1.5 to 1.8 & Java 1.7 to 1.8. unable to open input stream for resource

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, dxa-1.8

I have upgraded **DXA(Java) 1.5 to 1.8 & Java 1.7 to 1.8**  I can able to compile successfully but when I start execute my app in WebSphere am getting run time exception: `com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl scanJAR unable to open input stream for resource scala/util/hashing/MurmurHash3$ArrayHashing$mcI$sp.class in archive WEB-INF/lib/scala-library-2.12.2.jar java.lang.RuntimeException`

************ Start Display Current Environment ************

```
WebSphere Platform 8.5.5.10 [BASE 8.5.5.10 cf101629.01] [IBMJAVA7 7.0.6.1 cf021412.02] [IBMJAVA71 7.1.3.10 cf081545.02] [IBMJAVA8 8.0.3.20 cf111647.02] running with process name NW165389Node01Cell\NW165389Node01\server1 and process id 21860
Host Operating System is Windows 10, version 10.0
Java version = 1.8.0, Java Runtime Version = pwa6480sr3fp20ifx-20161110_01 (SR3 FP20+IV90630+IV90578), Java Compiler = j9jit28, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM
was.install.root = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer
user.install.root = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01
Java Home = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.8_64\jre
ws.ext.dirs = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/java_1.8_64/lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01/classes;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/classes;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/installedChannels;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/ext;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/web/help;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/deploytool/itp/plugins/com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy/runtime
Classpath = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01/properties;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/properties;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/startup.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/jsf-nls.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/lmproxy.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/urlprotocols.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/deploytool/itp/batchboot.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/deploytool/itp/batch2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/java_1.8_64/lib/tools.jar
Java Library path = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/native/win/x86_64/;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\jre\bin\compressedrefs;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\jre\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\native\win\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\jre\bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Client\12c\12102~1.0X8\Client\BIN;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\ESD\Utilities;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lotus\Notes;C:\Program Files (x86)\Simon Tatham\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\maven\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\1E\NomadBranch\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Ruby25-x64\bin;C:\Ruby24-x64\bin;C:\Ruby23-x64\bin;C:\Users\devarj1\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\devarj1\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;C:\Users\devarj1\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\devarj1\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\devarj1\AppData\Roaming\npm;D:\Jai\Software\eclipse-jee-oxygen-3a-win32-x86_64\eclipse;.;
Orb Version = IBM Java ORB build orb80-20161012.00
************* End Display Current Environment *************
CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1584)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doRequestWork(Connection.java:3190)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:3051)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:64)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)

[11/14/18 13:44:59:078 EST] 00000061 ecs           W com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl scanJAR unable to open input stream for resource scala/util/hashing/MurmurHash3$ArrayHashing$mcI$sp.class in archive WEB-INF/lib/scala-library-2.12.2.jar
                                 java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitParameter(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:149)
    at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:124)
    at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.impl.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:120)
    at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.scanJAR(ScannerContextImpl.java:275)
    at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.scanJARs(ScannerContextImpl.java:315)
    at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.WARScannerContext.scanInternal(WARScannerContext.java:76)
    at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.scan(ScannerContextImpl.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.getScannedClasses(ScannerContextImpl.java:70)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.scanForHandlesTypesClasses(WebAppImpl.java:764)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:605)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:409)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:170)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:901)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1179)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1390)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:979)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:778)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1381)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2192)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:435)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:378)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:126)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:653)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5396)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5612)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:667)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:611)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1271)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1263)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:620)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1257)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1096)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl._startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1482)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1371)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1320)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1263)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:620)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1257)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1096)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.remote.AdminServiceForwarder.invoke(AdminServiceForwarder.java:346)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1479)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:87)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1320)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1412)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:840)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi._RMIConnectionImpl_Tie.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi._RMIConnectionImpl_Tie._invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:638)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:508)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:613)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1584)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doRequestWork(Connection.java:3190)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:3051)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:64)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)

[11/14/18 13:44:59:079 EST] 00000061 ecs           W com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl scanJAR unable to open input stream for resource scala/util/hashing/MurmurHash3$ArrayHashing$mcJ$sp.class in archive WEB-INF/lib/scala-library-2.12.2.jar
                                 java.lang.RuntimeException
```

Comment: Seems to look like something specific to Websphere related error, try the following links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050181/unable-to-open-input-stream-for-resource-class-in-archive-war

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI89708

Comment: https://github.com/x-stream/xstream/issues/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is "WebSphere Application Server traditional V8.5" is not supporting Java 1.8 based built jar's and app. upgraded it to "WebSphere Application Server traditional V9.0"